# How to display the formatted Html in WPF control other than webbrowser control?

Tags: html, .net, wpf, browser

How to display the formatted `HTML` in WPF control other than `WebBrowser` control?

Answer (score 3):

You can use RichTextBox.

Check project [Html To RichTextBox](https://htmltorichtextbox.codeplex.com/) on codeplex.com.

Comment: thanks. that control won't work for me but got the idea to write similar control to satisfy all the requirements.

Comment: @hanskishore why it doesn't work for you? Do you get any errors?

Answer (score 1):

You can convert HTML to a FlowDocument and display that. Good to do it with an XSL transform, unless your subset of HTML tags is super-limited.